# Symfony FilterForm not properly rendering html

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

I tried to change the ForeignKey Select boxes of my FilterForm to simple inputs:

```
$this->widgetSchema['partner_id'] = new sfWidgetFormFilterInput(array('with_empty' => false));
```

formerly (within setWidgets):

```
'partner_id'    => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Partner'), 'add_empty' => true))
```

After the change Symfony perfectly renders the form, but the name of the partner_id input is now `receipt_filters[partner_id][text]` something that does not make sense.
And this breaks the whole filter if I try to POST this to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a simple sfWidgetFormInput()
this won't generate the [text] part of the name, wich is use in order to filter on string with LIKE operator in sql.

Comment: But I want to use a input instead of a dropdown, because if I have 1000 entries, it would take ages to render the select.
And I adjusted the validator to:
$this->setWidget('partner_id', new sfWidgetFormFilterInput(array('with_empty' => false)));

Comment: excuse me, I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I see you updated your question. Well I ll see whether this works and report back to you.